# Can't sample hardware cache events with linux perf

Tags: linux, profiling, cpu-cache, perf

For some reason, I can't sample (`perf record`) hardware cache events:

```
# perf record -e L1-dcache-stores -a -c 100 -- sleep 5
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.607 MB perf.data (~26517 samples) ]
# perf script
```

but I can count them (`perf stat`):

```
# perf stat -e L1-dcache-stores -a -- sleep 5
  Performance counter stats for 'sleep 5':

     711,781 L1-dcache-stores                                            

     5.000842990 seconds time elapsed
```

I tried on different CPUs, OS versions (and kernel versions), `perf` versions but the result is the same. Is this an expected behaviour? What is the reason? Can't `perf` warn about this?

Comment: Do you have root access?

Comment: Yes, the scnipped posted in the question were taken as root. It works the same with and without root.

Comment: same problem, any updates?

Comment: @papirrin: No, I tried asking on #perf some time ago but there was no one active at that mooment. As a workaround you can try sampling using a a CPU/arch-specific performance event with the syntax `cpu/event=0x40,umask=0x128/u` (and the suitable values of `event` and `umask`).

Comment: ysdx, actually there are some events in `perf report` but still no output from `perf script` (tested `L1-dcache-stores -a -c 100` with core i7 and ubuntu 14.10). May be we should try `perf script -D` option to debug perf.data and perf script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference in `perf evlist -vvv` output of three perf.data, one of cache event, second of software event, and last of hw cycles event:

```
echo '2^234567 %2' | perf record -e L1-dcache-stores -c 100 -o cache bc
echo '2^234567 %2' | perf record -e cycles -c 100 -o cycles bc
echo '2^234567 %2' | perf record -e cs -c 100 -o cs bc

 perf evlist -vvv -i cache
L1-dcache-stores: sample_freq=100, type: 3, config: 256, size: 96, sample_type: IP|TID|TIME, disabled: 1, inherit: 1, mmap: 1, mmap2: 1, comm: 1, enable_on_exec: 1, sample_id_all: 1, exclude_guest: 1
 perf evlist -vvv -i cycles
cycles: sample_freq=100, size: 96, sample_type: IP|TID|TIME, disabled: 1, inherit: 1, mmap: 1, mmap2: 1, comm: 1, enable_on_exec: 1, sample_id_all: 1, exclude_guest: 1
 perf evlist -vvv -i cs
cs: sample_freq=100, type: 1, config: 3, size: 96, sample_type: IP|TID|TIME, disabled: 1, inherit: 1, mmap: 1, mmap2: 1, comm: 1, enable_on_exec: 1, sample_id_all: 1, exclude_guest: 1
```

There are different types, and types are defined as

```
0028 enum perf_type_id {
0029     PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE          = 0,
0030     PERF_TYPE_SOFTWARE          = 1,
0031     PERF_TYPE_TRACEPOINT            = 2,
0032     PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE          = 3,
0033     PERF_TYPE_RAW               = 4,
0034     PERF_TYPE_BREAKPOINT            = 5,
0035 
0036     PERF_TYPE_MAX,              /* non-ABI */
0037 };
```

Perf script has a `output` table which defines how to print event of every kind: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/builtin-script.c?v=3.16#L68

```
 68 /* default set to maintain compatibility with current format */
 69 static struct {
 70         bool user_set;
 71         bool wildcard_set;
 72         unsigned int print_ip_opts;
 73         u64 fields;
 74         u64 invalid_fields;
 75 } output[PERF_TYPE_MAX] = {
 76 
 77         [PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE] = {
 78                 .user_set = false,
 79 
 80                 .fields = PERF_OUTPUT_COMM | PERF_OUTPUT_TID |
 81                               PERF_OUTPUT_CPU | PERF_OUTPUT_TIME |
 82                               PERF_OUTPUT_EVNAME | PERF_OUTPUT_IP |
 83                                   PERF_OUTPUT_SYM | PERF_OUTPUT_DSO,
 84 
 85                 .invalid_fields = PERF_OUTPUT_TRACE,
 86         },
 87 
 88         [PERF_TYPE_SOFTWARE] = {
 89                 .user_set = false,
 90 
 91                 .fields = PERF_OUTPUT_COMM | PERF_OUTPUT_TID |
 92                               PERF_OUTPUT_CPU | PERF_OUTPUT_TIME |
 93                               PERF_OUTPUT_EVNAME | PERF_OUTPUT_IP |
 94                                   PERF_OUTPUT_SYM | PERF_OUTPUT_DSO,
 95 
 96                 .invalid_fields = PERF_OUTPUT_TRACE,
 97         },
 98 
 99         [PERF_TYPE_TRACEPOINT] = {
100                 .user_set = false,
101 
102                 .fields = PERF_OUTPUT_COMM | PERF_OUTPUT_TID |
103                                   PERF_OUTPUT_CPU | PERF_OUTPUT_TIME |
104                                   PERF_OUTPUT_EVNAME | PERF_OUTPUT_TRACE,
105         },
106 
107         [PERF_TYPE_RAW] = {
108                 .user_set = false,
109 
110                 .fields = PERF_OUTPUT_COMM | PERF_OUTPUT_TID |
111                               PERF_OUTPUT_CPU | PERF_OUTPUT_TIME |
112                               PERF_OUTPUT_EVNAME | PERF_OUTPUT_IP |
113                                   PERF_OUTPUT_SYM | PERF_OUTPUT_DSO,
114 
115                 .invalid_fields = PERF_OUTPUT_TRACE,
116         },
117 };
118
```

So, there is no instructions of printing any of field from samples with type 3 - PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE, and `perf script` does not print them. We can try to register this type in `output` array and even push the patch to kernel.

Comment: Nice! I'll try to have a look a this when I managed to find some time.

Comment: I have this issue in Ubuntu 16.04. When I tested in Ubuntu 18.04 it seems fixed there.