# perf.data to text or csv

Tags: linux, profiling, performancecounter, perf

I am using 'perf record' command to sample hardware counters at 1 ms. It provides me a 'perf.data' as the output file but I am not aware of any tool/command that will help me to read the counter data from the 'perf.data' binary file into a text or CSV file. Or simply put, I need to read the hardware counter event data at every 1ms from the 'perf.data' file.

Some more Details:

1. I have used 'perf stat' command to get hardware counter event data at 10ms but it doesn't allow sampling at sampling interval less than 10ms. So, I am using 'perf record' instead of perf stat to sample at 1ms.
   Some useful links which convinced me to use perf record:
   [Perf Stat vs Perf Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49216628/perf-stat-vs-perf-record) and
   [Collecting the data for a partiulcar process from PMU for every 1 milli second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49762198/collecting-the-data-for-a-partiulcar-process-from-pmu-for-every-1-milli-second)
2. I have also tried 'perf script' but it only provides support some hardware events. For example: cache events are not supported by perf script. link: [Can't sample hardware cache events with linux perf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26909493/cant-sample-hardware-cache-events-with-linux-perf/28803176#28803176)

Can anyone help me with this, please? Please assume that I know how to use perf record command and already have the perf.data file(generated from perf record)

Edited: Following are the commands and their output message on the terminal using the feedback from the answers:

## **1)** *perf record -e LLC-stores,LLC-loads,cache-misses -F 999 -R -T ls>ls.txt*

**output:**

```
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.017 MB perf.data (28 samples) ]
```

## **2)** *perf report -F sample,period --stdio*

**output:**

```
Total Lost Samples: 0
Samples: 9  of event 'LLC-stores'
Event count (approx.): 7440
     Samples        Period
............  ............
         9          7440

Samples: 9  of event 'LLC-loads'
Event count (approx.): 50008
     Samples        Period
............  ............
         9         50008

Samples: 10  of event 'cache-misses'
Event count (approx.): 351826
     Samples        Period
............  ............
        10        351826
```

## **3)** *perf script -F period,event*

**output:**

```
     1   LLC-stores: 
     1    LLC-loads: 
     1 cache-misses: 
     1    LLC-loads: 
     1 cache-misses: 
    61    LLC-loads: 
    58 cache-misses: 
  3097 cache-misses: 
     1   LLC-stores: 
    13   LLC-stores: 
  4748    LLC-loads: 
  1390   LLC-stores: 
190186 cache-misses: 
     1   LLC-stores: 
     1    LLC-loads: 
     1 cache-misses: 
     1    LLC-loads: 
     1 cache-misses: 
     1   LLC-stores: 
    52 cache-misses: 
    50    LLC-loads: 
    20   LLC-stores: 
  4110 cache-misses: 
  2002    LLC-loads: 
   748   LLC-stores: 
154319 cache-misses: 
 43143    LLC-loads: 
  5265   LLC-stores:
```

## **4)** *perf stat -I 1 -e LLC-stores,LLC-loads,cache-misses ls>ls.txt*

**output:**

```
       time             counts unit events
 0.006476856              1,115      LLC-stores
 0.006476856             13,121      LLC-loads
 0.006476856              9,371      cache-misses
```

Both *perf report* and *perf script* provide number of samples,period and event name but not the event count for each sample. It would be really helpful if you could tell me how to get the event count for the each 28 samples that we get from perf record.

Comment: "I am not able to parse this file to text or CSV", "I need to read the hardware counter event data at every 1ms and I am not able to do it from the 'perf.data' file" Share why this is the case.

Comment: @jdv, I am not able to parse this file file to csv or text because I do not know/I am not aware of any tool/command which converts the 'perf.data' file(a binary file) to text or csv. Thank you for pointing it out. I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: So, this is more of a query into the format of the perf.data file? If so, then your best bet is to research this format and the many tools available to read and access that data. A web search like "perf perf.data format" should get you started. Unfortunately, this is probably off-topic for this site unless you wanted help with a specific script or program that you were writing to solve this problem. You might get better results researching over on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Hi @onkar.omr do you want the number of event counts per sample ? Or the total number of events in total ?

Comment: @ArnabjyotiKalita, I want the number of events counts per sample.

Comment: @onkar.omr I added some more details. Let me know if this is satisfactory.

Comment: @ArnabjyotiKalita, I did get the results as you suggested. Thanks! However, many PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE entries do not mention which counter(cache misses or ref-cycles) has been recorded for that instance/sample(Some samples show a particular counter but most of them do not have the name of the counter in the data). Does this mean I have to do this for every time for each counter? This would really make my work hard/cumbersome and time consuming. Would you please suggest any other method/idea(other than perf) to get hardware counters at every 1ms?

Comment: @ArnabjyotiKalita, My basic requirement is I need to study the behaviour of the application based on the trace of hardware counter(over time @ 1ms). I am looking at Intel Vtune, it does sample at 1ms but I am not getting a timeline based hardware events data. Please let me know if you can think of anything that would be useful. Thank you so much. You have been so helpful.

Comment: Hi @onkar.omr have you tried to use `perf script -D` also to determine which sample belongs to which event ? No you do not need to do this separately for each counter. You can always use multiple events to record samples for at the same time, however if the number of events exceed the number of performance counters, there will be some degree of multiplexing. The mechanism of `perf` should be sufficient for you to get the results given your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `perf record -e <event-name> ...` to sample events every 1ms. It seems you are trying to read the `perf.data` file and organize it into human-readable data. You should use `perf report` if you are not aware of it. The `perf report` command reads the `perf.data` file and generates a concise execution profile. The below link should help you -

[Sample analysis with perf report](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Sample_analysis_with_perf_report)

You can modify the `perf report` output to your requirements. You can also use `perf report -F` to specify multiple columns in csv format.

However, in addition, `perf stat` does have a mechanism to collect information in a csv format using the `perf stat -x` command.

Edit #1:

(I am using Linux-Kernel 4.14.3 for evaluation.)

Since you want the number of events per sample taken, there are couple of things to be noted. To count the number of events per sample, you will need to know the sampling period. The sampling period gives you the number of events after which the performance counter will overflow and the kernel will record a sample. So essentially, in your case,

`sampling period = number of events per sample`

Now there are two ways of specifying this sampling period. Either you specify it or you do not specify it.

If while doing a `perf record`, you specify the sampling period.. something like this :-

`perf record -e <some_event_name> -c 1000 ...`

Here -c 1000 means that the sampling period is 1000. In this case, you purposefully force the system to record 1000 events per sample because the sampling period is fixed by you.

On the other hand, if you do not specify the sampling period, the system will try to record events at a default frequency of **1000 samples/sec**. This means that the system will automatically change the sampling period, if need be, to maintain the frequency of 1000 samples/sec. In such a case, to determine the sampling period, you need to observe the `perf.data` file.

Specifically, you need to open the `perf.data` file using the command :

`perf script -D`

The output will very well look like this :-

```
0 0 0x108 [0x38]: PERF_RECORD_FORK(1:1):(0:0)

0x140 [0x30]: event: 3
.
. ... raw event: size 48 bytes
.  0000:  03 00 00 00 00 00 30 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  ......0.........
.  0010:  73 79 73 74 65 6d 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  systemd.........
.  0020:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

0 0 0x140 [0x30]: PERF_RECORD_COMM: systemd:1/1

0x170 [0x38]: event: 7
.
. ... raw event: size 56 bytes
.  0000:  07 00 00 00 00 00 38 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ......8.........
.  0010:  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
.  0020:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
.  0030:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                          ........
```

You can see different types of records like `PERF_RECORD_FORK` and `PERF_RECORD_COMM` and even `PERF_RECORD_MMAP`. You need to specifically look out for records that begin with **PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE** inside the file. Like this:

```
14 173826354106096 0x10d40 [0x28]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x1): 28179/28179: 0xffffffffa500d3b5 period: 3000 addr: 0
 ... thread: perf:28179
 ...... dso: [kernel.kallsyms]
            perf 28179 [014] 173826.354106: cache-misses:  ffffffffa500d3b5 [unknown] ([kernel.kallsyms])
```

As you can see, in this case the period is 3000 i.e. number of events collected between the previous sampling event and this sampling event is 3000. (i.e. number of events per sample is 3000) Note that, as I mentioned above this period might be tuned. So you need to collect all of the **PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE** records from the `perf.data` file.

Comment: As I said, you should use the `perf report` command to see a readable format of the `perf.data` file.

Comment: Thanks! I have edited the question with your comments and feedback.can you please take a look at the revised question.